# ReadOnly combobox in Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

i am trying to have a combobox in Extjs such that user should not edit the default value which is already available :

Here is the code i tried:::

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],

    data: [{
        "abbr": "AL",
        "name": "Alabama"
    }, {
        "abbr": "AK",
        "name": "Alaska"
    }, {
        "abbr": "AZ",
        "name": "Arizona"
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    editable:false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    // Template for the dropdown menu.
    // Note the use of "x-boundlist-item" class,
    // this is required to make the items selectable.
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<tpl for=".">', '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{abbr} - {name}</div>', '</tpl>'),
    // template for the content inside text field
    displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<tpl for=".">', '{abbr} - {name}', '</tpl>')
}); 
});
```

Although i do editable:false ... but it didnt work.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some cache problem , editable:false was not working

however it is correct solution